# How to upload file on an online link using mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image file on an online link of a domain i have bought. Link is live. I can upload it in a local directory. but not working for online link. I cant find the correct way to give online path of my online directory to command

> string filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("???");

here is the code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateBanners(UpdateBanners banner)
    {

        zasa_company_slider sliderData = new zasa_company_slider();

        if (banner != null && banner.file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            string filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("http://ak.eat-ax.com/akpanel/images/" + Path.GetFileName(banner.file.FileName));
            banner.file.SaveAs(filePath);

        }


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), banner.file.FileName);`

Comment: Is ak.eat-ax.com the actual address your server is hosted at? If it's not, then MapPath can't help you. If it is, have you tried removing it and just passing in the virtual path (starting with ~/akpanel)?

Comment: have tried that too. it still makes the local link.. instead of accessing http link. @StephenMuecke

Comment: it is the actual address of my server. but am trying to upload image from another project at that address. @DylanNicholson

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood - Is that address on a different server?

Comment: What do you mean "another project"? A different web service? What's the actual value returned from MapPath("~/akpanel") vs what you actually hope to see?

Comment: I want the output to be http://ak.eat-ax.com/akpanel/images/
but it gives address of local path where my project is placed in my computer.

Comment: And it says it cannot find the path.

Comment: am trying to upload at that address from a local project.

Comment: You can't just "save" something to a remote http server using its http address unless you have 1) a [webdav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server running on that adress 2) you use a webdav client (https://github.com/saguiitay/WebDAVClient). It's relatively rare for bought hosting though. How do you normally interact with files on this other server? ftp? then you should use its ftp endpoint and an [ftp client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ...or you could implement an api method on the second server that accepts a filestream.

Comment: Thanks For your answers ! I got it :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve your images like this

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + Path.GetFileName(index.FileName));
                        index.SaveAs(filePath);

                        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
                        foreach (string var in filePaths)
                        {
                            if (Path.GetFileName(var) == index.FileName)
                            {
                                sliderData.SLIDER_IMAGE = ("liveServerURL/" + Path.GetFileName(var));
                            }

                        }
```